ASP.NET Core 8.0 Razor Pages: rewriting _Layout.cshtml.css => {application}.styles.css not found (404)
After making a new .NET8.0 Razor Pages (ASP.NET Core) project, I removed JQuery- and Bootstrap-Libraries. Then I edited _Layout.cshtml.css. When running the project, my CSS-rules are not applied, because my browser cannot load the stylesheet. The browser gets a 404 as result, when requesting {application}.styles.css.
Does anyone know what the issue is?
The _Layout.cshtml and _Layout.cshtml.css look like this:


:root {

}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Inter";
    src: url(/fonts/Inter/Inter-VariableFont_slnt\,wght.ttf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Cutive Mono";
    src: url(/fonts/Cutive_Mono/CutiveMono-Regular.ttf);
}

html {
    font-family: Inter;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    margin: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 4.4rem 1fr 1.5rem;
}

header {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1.5rem;
}

.main-header {
    background-color: blue;
}

.main-nav {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.main-nav-item {
    margin-left: 0.2rem;
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: inherit;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de-de">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"]</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/{application}.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="main-header"></div>
        <nav class="main-nav">
            <a href="#" class="main-nav-item">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#" class="main-nav-item">Link 2</a>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <main>
        @RenderBody()
    </main>

    <footer>
    </footer>

    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>



wwwroot looks like this:


where is your {application}.styles.css? does it exist in wwwroot folder?

I found out that this file is generated during build, by collecting and modifying several .css-files (each of them bound to a razor page by name-convention) (= CSS isolation). In my case, it doesn't seem to be generated, and haven't found the reason yet...

I found the issue:
When making a project My Project.csproj, the namespace My_Project (with underscore) is generated.
I used the namespace for the filepath:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/My_Project.styles.css" />

But I had to use the actual project name (without underscore):
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/My Project.styles.css" />


I created a new MVC application in my side and just like what you shared, I removed bootstrape and jquery lib in the project, then comment the reference to these libs in _Layout.cshtml. Then I created Index.cshtml.css and use it in my Index.cshtml, it worked in my side.

I also test to comment <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/WebApplication2.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />, then my custom style won't be used, but since it doesn't refer to the ApplicationName.stype.css, so that I didn't get 404 error. The same in a new .net 8 razor web app. I'm afraid you could clean and rebuild your app, and checking whether you have <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/WebApplication2.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" /> in your _layout.cshtml.

If this doesn't help to solve your issue, could you pls share a minimal sample for reproducing the issue?

I found the issue as described in my answer. Thanks, anyway!
